# Runtime analysis of a recursive function that calls another recursive function

Tags: c, recursion, big-o, computer-science, code-analysis

```
int f(int x)
{
  if (x < 1) return 1;

  return f(x-1) + g(x);
}


int g(int x)
{
  if (x < 2) return 1;

  return f(x-1) + g(x/2)
}
```

What is big-O of f? More importantly, what technique is used to calculate runtime for problems like this?

Comment: Looks like homework to me ! Do you mind to share any attempt ?

Comment: What do you do in your class?

Comment: @RontogiannisAristofanis There is nothing wrong with homework questions.

Comment: It was an interview question. If it was homework I wouldn't need to ask here. :)

Comment: Thanks for asking this. Made me implement the "mutual recursion" type forward declarations in my Pascal compiler. ;)

Comment: @Lother sorry, my bad :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets write `Cf(x)` (resp `Cg(x)`) the number of addition performed when calling `f(x)` (resp `g(x)`).

First of all both function are returning some number which are obtained by addition going back ultimately to 1. Therefore

```
Cf(x) = f(x) - 1
Cg(x) = g(x) - 1
```

So let's stick to f and g. Here are the first few values:

```
[(f(i), g(i), 2^i) for i in range(10)]
[(1, 1, 1),
 (2, 1, 2),
 (5, 3, 4),
 (11, 6, 8),
 (25, 14, 16),
 (53, 28, 32),
 (112, 59, 64),
 (230, 118, 128),
 (474, 244, 256),
 (962, 488, 512)]
```

Looks exponential. Moreover:

```
f(x) = f(x-1) + g(x) 
     = 2*f(x-1) + g(x/2)
```

This clearly indicate that

```
f(x) > 2*f(x-1) > 4*f(x-2) > 8*f(x-3) > 2^x.
```

So you are good betting that `f(x)` is a `O(2^x)`, actually a `Theta(2^x)`.

Now `f(x) > 2^x` and `f(x-1) <= g(x) <= f(x)`. So that `g` and `f` grows at the same rate.
As a consequence `g(x/2)` is completely negligible compared to `f(x)`. So that

```
f(x) is a O(2^n)
```

Comment: Thank you. I think the key for me here is where you broke out the relationship f(x) > 2*f(x-1) and show how as n approaches the bottom linearly the growth factor is exponential. It has been about 10 years since I've seen any of this in a classroom but I don't remember doing this particular kind of analysis. Of course all of the easy ones come up in interviews (runtime of sort or BFS/DFS, etc..) but this was my first encounter with one like this. Again, thanks for this.